# How to autoupdate version number on successful build of an R package

Tags: r, package, rstudio, package-development

I found this [article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-auto-update-a-package-version-number/) ([original](http://www.mango-solutions.com/wp/2015/09/how-to-auto-update-a-package-version-number-3/)) about how to auto update a package version number in R.

I would like to implement it in the same way as they suggest **but I fail at the point to create my own `Makefile` to build a package**.

The function they provide is working fine.

Can anyone help me to create a `Makefile` to check, build, if both are successful increase the version number, build under new version number. Within RStudio it is possible to select `Makefile` as build tool.

In general I like the idea to have all development packages with a 4th version number like `0.1.2.9001`. At the moment I always overwrite my packages and only set three numbers manually like `0.1.3`.

Comment: You're describing a build pipeline there, I'm unsure a Makefile could do, you'd better look over tooling around like Jenkins (first in my mind, there's others). Search around build pipeline and continuous integration for guidance on practices around this.

Comment: @Tensibai you might be correct that CI is the better solution but might also be over the top for some packages. I was also trying to set up jenkins on my project but this might be a bit more complex then just creating a make file which checks, builds, and if this build had no errors, build with new version number. I would really appreciate if you could open this topic again.

Comment: @Tensibai also the reason is I am not directly asking for **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource**. But I am asking for help to create a `Makefile` which I can use in RStudio. Also the the +3 vote shows that other people might be interested.

Comment: You're assuming I've more power than it is. I can NOT hold a question by myself nor reopen it alone. It need the  consensus of 5 people

Comment: And the +3 just mean there's only 3 other people just as non aware of SO behavior as you are. you're clearly asking for a tutorial here.

Comment: @Tensibai I thought so since you were in the list of these 5 people... I am also open to rephrase my question. I already edited it a little so it is no longer asking for a recommendation but more for help

Comment: It is still not showing what effort you put to try resolving it by yourself, I'm at lunch actually we can go to a chat room to discuss this more deeply in around 20 mins if you're OK for this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92847/discussion-between-drmariod-and-tensibai).